# How can I estimate the force of an electromagnet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am doing an experiment on electromagnetism, basically I am just testing the pulling force of an electromagnet using a newton meter with a magnetic hook and seeing how the pulling force changes as i decrease the amount of coils. Part of the experiment is comparing my experimental data to the expected results, the problem is I don’t know how to find these expected results. my electromagnet has a regular cylindrical core which I assume simplifies a lot of things. Is there any way in which i could estimate the pulling force of the magnet? Thanks.

Comment: The pulling force at a given distance should be proportional  to B and this you can calculate for your coil.

Comment: @trula Force is proportional to the variation of the magnetic energy density. Therefore, it is proportional to $B^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia article on Electromagnets might help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet

The forces are highly dependent on the geometry. But if you have core then this will mostly determine the shape of the magnetic field lines. The field will be proportional the the current and the number of turns on the coil. $ I \cdot N $ The force will be proportional to the product of the strength of your magnet and the one that you attach for testing.

If the magnet used for testing is weak (has almost no field of its own) and your magnet strong then the force will be more determined by $ B^2 $.

Also the core material could be saturated and then you ave a non-linearity but you will most likely not get to that range.